# Using Pycharm I don't get any output once code is run, just Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, pycharm

So pretty much, I have a directory that contains many of 2 types of text files, a bunch of files that begin with "summary_" and a bunch of files that begin with "log". All these text are in the same directory. For now I don't care about the "log" text files, I only care about the files that start with "summary".

Each "summary" file contains either 7 lines of text or 14 lines of text.
At the end of each line it will say either PASS or FAIL depending on the test result. For the test result to be passing all 7 or 14 lines have to say "PASS" at the end. If one of those lines have just one "FAIL" in it, The test has failed. I want to count the number of passes and failures.

```
import os
import glob

def pass_or_fail_counter():

    pass_count = 0
    fail_count = 0

    os.chdir("/home/dario/Documents/Log_Test")
    print("Working directory is ") + os.getcwd()
    data = open('*.txt').read()
    count = data.count('PASS')

    if count == 7 or 14:
        pass_count = pass_count + 1
    else:
        fail_count = fail_count + 1
    print(pass_count)
    print(fail_count)
    f.close()

pass_or_fail_counter()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It might explain the behavior.

Comment: By the way all my indentations are 4 spaces in after defining the function.

Comment: Your last line shouldn't be indented. The way it's written, a function gets defined and the program ends, with no execution of that function.

Comment: This part looks suspicious: `if count == 7 or 14:` . I think you meant to write something like `if count in (7, 14):`

Comment: Pretty much I wanted to write. if the amount of times that "PASS" is present in each file is == to the number 7 or the number 14, Then do this.

Comment: Nearo, I unindented the last line and still no output.

Comment: What you want to write should be `if count in (7, 14):` instead of `if count == 7 or 14:` (which returns True for 7 and 14 for any other vale of count), but it is not good either: if you have 14 lines and 7 PASS, it will count as a pass, which it should not. Instead you should compare your count to the number of lines in the file. Besides, your code is obviously not executed, or you would get an error at `f.close()`, since f is not defined (I guess you meant data).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about within Pycharm, but the following seems to work without it:

```
import os
import glob

def pass_or_fail_counter(logdir):
    pass_count, fail_count = 0, 0

    for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(logdir, '*.txt')):
        with open(filename, 'rt') as file:
            lines = file.read().splitlines()

        if len(lines) in {7, 14}:  # right length?
            if "PASS" in lines[-1]:  # check last line for result
                pass_count += 1
            else:
                fail_count += 1

    print(pass_count, fail_count)

pass_or_fail_counter("/home/dario/Documents/Log_Test")
```